# Store Java enum's String value instead of enum value itself in DynamoDB

Tags: java, persistence, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB and I would like to store the `enum`'s `String` values instead of the `enum` itself.

For instance, I have this `enum`:

```
public enum Source {
  BREACH("breach"),
  LEAKAGE("leakage");

  private final String desc;

  Source(String desc) { this.desc = desc; }

  public String desc() { return desc; }
}
```

...and this "entity":

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Alerts")
public final class Alert implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4012517315640518044L;

  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "AlertId") // Partition Key or Hash Attribute
  private String alertId;

  @DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Source")
  private Source type;

  // Constructor(s), Getter(s), Setter(s), ToString, etc...
}
```

With the `@DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum` annotation, the value that gets saved is `BREACH`, but I want `breach`.

```
{
  "AlertId": { "S": "a083168d-cb23-4ec8-ab80-a1c16955c4b8" },
  "Source": { "S": "BREACH" },
  ...
  "CreatedAt": { "S": "2017-05-03T14:07:36.395Z" }
}
```

Any clues? I did try "converters" (not fully, I couldn't make it work though) but I think I have to end up doing one for each `enum` type since they are all different.

Answer (score 1):

You can code the Alert class like this i.e. define the attribute as String and design the `getter` and `setter` to send/receive **enum** object (i.e. Source).

**Alert class:-**

```
    @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Alerts")
public final class Alert implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4012517315640518044L;

    private String alertId;

    private String type;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "AlertId") 
    public String getAlertId() {
        return alertId;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Source")
    public Source getType() {
      if (type != null)
        return Source.valueOf(type);
      else
        return null;
    }

    public void setAlertId(String alertId) {
        this.alertId = alertId;
    }

    public void setType(Source type) {
        this.type = type.desc();
    }
}
```

**Create Alert:-**

Stores the value as expected on database table. The get item from DynamoDB table also works fine.

```
public Boolean createAlert(String alertId, Source source) {
    DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);
    Alert alert = new Alert();
    alert.setAlertId(alertId);
    alert.setType(source);
    dynamoDBMapper.save(alert);

    return true;

}
```

Comment: I tried that also; the issue with this approach is when the value was `null` before persisting it. It fails when it tries to "find" the entity back from DynamoDB. Sometimes `source` can be present or not. If the value is there always there are no issues, but that's not the case for me.

Comment: The latest update on getType method should handle the scenario where Source is not present on table. The DynamoDB get should work and object should be deserialized properly.

Comment: Yeah! I get it, but I'm looking for something different: one custom annotation or something similar. I wouldn't like to handle those `null` values; I would rather stay with the built-in `@DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum`. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm having same issues. Is anyone able to solve this issue with DynamoDB? Even the solution given by @notionquest and sam is not working

Answer (score 0):

Override toString() this should work.

```
public enum Source {

  BREACH("breach"),
  LEAKAGE("leakage");

  private final String desc;

  Source(String desc) { this.desc = desc; }

  public String desc() { return desc; }

  @Override
  public String toString() { return desc; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by defining a custom attribute converter. It works but I'm afraid you'd have to write converters for each enum.

There is already method for serializing `desc()`.We can define a static method for deserializing `toSource()`
**Source.java**

```
public enum Source {
    BREACH("breach"),
    LEAKAGE("leakage");

    private final String desc;

    Source(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String desc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public static Source toSource(String value) {
        return Arrays.stream(Source.values()).filter(et -> et.desc().equals(value)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
}
```

We can then define a custom DynamoDBType converter:

**SourceEnumDynamoDbConverter.java**

```
public class SourceEnumDynamoDbConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, Source> {
    @Override
    public String convert(Source source) {
        return source.desc();
    }

    @Override
    public Source unconvert(String sourceStr) {
        return Source.toSource(sourceStr);
    }
}
```

And finally annotate our Entity's `Source` property with this custom converter
**Alert.java**

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Alerts")
public final class Alert implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4012517315640518044L;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "AlertId") // Partition Key or Hash Attribute
    private String alertId;

    private Source type;

    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = TrialEnumDynamoDbConverter.class)
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Source")
    public Source getSource() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setSource(Source type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    // Constructor(s), Getter(s), Setter(s), ToString, etc...
}
```

This way `desc` is stored and read from dynamodb resulting in

```
{
  "AlertId": { "S": "a083168d-cb23-4ec8-ab80-a1c16955c4b8" },
  "Source": { "S": "breach" },
  ...
  "CreatedAt": { "S": "2017-05-03T14:07:36.395Z" }
}
```